# Map to customized (dynamically generated but with same structure) tables entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have dbcontext class let's say.

"**tblProp**".

On querying I want it to point to "**tblProp_1**" when I pass 1 as an argument.

Is this type of querying through ef core possible?

There is class method in dbcontext named **entity.toTable("tblProp")**.

Is it possible to use that method to map to what I have described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is possible through [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore#linq2dbentityframeworkcore)

```
var items = context.DbSet<Table>().ToLinqToDBTable().TableName("table_3")
  .Where(...)
  .ToList();
```

For sure ChangeTracker will be not availaible but CRUD operation can be performed in other way:

```
var affected = context.DbSet<Table>().ToLinqToDBTable().TableName("table_3")
  .Where(...)
  .Set(v => v.Field, someValue)
  .Update();
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15753)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that provided that these databases share the same schema. You can create a parameterized constructor and pass the parameter whiling creating the DB context.

Comment: parameterized constructor of?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without calling `OnModelCreating` method which is called once per DbContext type and have the caching functionality.